# Compare function arguments in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, arguments, compare

I'm trying to write a simple comparison statement for multiple function arguments and it's bypassing the error. tbh, I'm not even sure I'm able to compare these arguments.

I tried to add a nested if to extract the error and it's returning unknown exception.  (uncomment the nested if to see the behavior)

```
var names = ["Hole-in-one!", "Eagle", "Birdie", "Par", "Bogey", "Double Bogey", "Go Home!"];
function golfScore(par, strokes) {
  if ((par || strokes) <= 0) {
    /*if (par) {
      return "Please enter a value greater than " + par + " for Par";
    }
    else if (strokes) { */
      return "Please enter a value greater than " + strokes + " for Strokes";
    }
  else if (strokes == 1) {
    return names[0];
  }
  else if (strokes <= (par - 2)) {
    return names[1];
  }
  else if (strokes == (par - 1)) {
    return names[2];
  }
  else if (strokes == (par)) {
    return names[3];
  }
  else if (strokes == (par + 1)) {
    return names[4];
  }
  else if (strokes == (par + 2)) {
    return names[5];
  }
    return names[6];
}

// Change these values to test
console.log(golfScore(0,1));console.log(golfScore(5,4));
```

Comment: If you remove the comments you will be missing a bracket to close the nested if statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
((par || strokes) <= 0)
```

The `||` makes it evaluate if `par` or `stroke` is not a "false" data type (false, null, undefined). Basically, you are trying to compare a boolean to a number. Instead, you should compare each one of your variables to 0

```
(par <= 0 || strokes <= 0)
```